# mongodb aggregate function google cloud console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-platform, meanjs

I have a strange problem regarding how mongodb works for my MEAN.js application. It's not a problem straight for MEAN app, but goes directly just for MONGODB.

On my local computer(Win 8.1) and a VM(Ubuntu server 14.x) aggregate functions with mongoose works fine, but when I upload my project with the same version of Mongodb to a Google Cloud Virtual Instance (2 CPU's or 4 CPU's) everything works fine, untill the aggregate function will be triggered. I do not have an error from the server to show, that's why is weird...
(MongoDB v3.2.8 or 3.2.6, both works for local) I tried on 3 different Google Cloud VI, but ended with the same result...

My query is about counting records for each day if found. Here is my query:

```
    { "$match": { '$and':
           [ { firm: ObjectId('574e81be2153f45b0c3d6811') },
             { created:
                { '$gte': ISODate('Tue Jul 12 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)'),
                  '$lte': ISODate('Thu Aug 11 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)') } },
             { transactionStatus: 1 } ] }
        },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "$add": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                { "$mod": [
                  { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                  OneDay
                ] }
              ] },
              new Date(0)
            ]
          },
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        } 
    }
```

I tried switching the MONGODB version to 2.6 or something similar, but still to a no end. I couldn't find anything similar here or anywhere else, that's why I am asking here.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why but if I change the query I am performing into the aggregation like this:

```
{ '$and':
  [ { created:
      { '$gte': ISODate('Tue Jul 12 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)'),
        '$lte': ISODate('Thu Aug 11 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)') } },
    { transactionStatus: 1 },
    { firm: ObjectId('574e81be2153f45b0c3d6811') }
  ] 
}
```

From this:

```
{ '$and':
  [ { firm: ObjectId('574e81be2153f45b0c3d6811') },
    { created:
      { '$gte': ISODate('Tue Jul 12 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)'),
        '$lte': ISODate('Thu Aug 11 2016 15:56:04 GMT+0000 (UTC)') } },
    { transactionStatus: 1 } 
  ] 
}
```

Works everything fine...can someone explain this to me? Anyways, this topic can be closed.